# php s3 downloading timesout in 120sec

Tags: php, amazon-s3

We have PHP script that downloads a file from S3 and uploads to a db but we've noticed that on large files, it seems to timeout and exactly at 120seconds. Can't quite point to where its at but here is how we run the download:

```
foreach ($dm_uploads as $row) {
    $filename = $row['filename'];
    tell("Loading rows from file $filename");
    tell("Starting file download from S3 (this is the slowest step)...");
    $object = Env::get("S3_BUCKET") . '/uploads/' . $filename;
    $file = fopen($object, 'r');            <----- I THINK ITS EITHER HERE
    $contents = stream_get_contents($file); <----- OR HERE
    tell("File downloaded from S3...");
    $contents = gzdecodeML($contents);
    tell("gunzipped file...");

    ... other stuff happens 
}
```

There error we get is the following:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'cURL_Exception' with message 'cURL resource: Resource id #10934; cURL error: Connection timed out after 120001 milliseconds (cURL error code 28). See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html for an explanation of error codes.' in /usr/share/php/AWSSDKforPHP/lib/requestcore/requestcore.class.php:824`

I looked at error code `28` which is:

```
CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT (28)

Operation timeout. The specified time-out period was reached according to the conditions.
```

but what I can't find is where that would be specified? in the `php.init` file, i don't see that in there and all it has is this:

```
[PHP]
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT
upload_max_filesize = 40M
post_max_size = 40M
memory_limit = 1024M
```

Comment: Have you tried [stream_set_timeout](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php)?

Comment: I think my answer is here: https://www.cbronline.com/news/aws-ddos-attack ...same day I was seeing the issue